# Dynamic facebook share page using sharer.php approach

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

My way to create a facebook share button is : 
  **1. create a share.php (facebook capture meta data in this fake website and redirect to the actual website i want to share**)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo $_GET['title'];?></title>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_GET['url'];?>" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $_GET['title'];?> "/>
        <? 
        if (isset($_GET['leftImg']) && $_GET['leftImg'] != 'undefined') {
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$_GET['leftImg'].'"/>';
        }
        if (isset($_GET['rightImg']) && $_GET['rightImg'] != 'undefined') {
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$_GET['rightImg'].'"/>';
        }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.location.href = "<?php echo $_GET['redirect'];?>";
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**2. The data need in share.php is passed from main page**

```
 window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent('http://' + window.location.hostname + '/share.php?url=http://yahoo.com&title=test&redirect=..&leftImg=......&' ),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=826px,height=536');
```

The problem is , **what should be the og:url**? There are two link : the share.php and the actual website I want to share,

**If I use share.php?title=...&description=.. , I still have to specific url**  and that is weird : it will be share.php?url=share.php?url=share.php and eventually I still can not reference the correct url for sharing

**If I use the actual website**, it can not collect any meta data, as my idea is all meta is on share.php

How to fix the problem ? thanks

**!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Updated on 11/4/2013:!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

I figured out the root problem , it is caused by different source of image:

```
eg. http://www.tekxon.com.pk/sites/all/themes/bluemasters/images/gallery/3.jpg
```

This image is capture by facebook on share page as expected, working flawlessly.

```
eg. http://54.251.107.161/source/test2/2012/05/07/0/3/A/Content/15/Pg015.png
```

This image ,hosted in my server , however, is not not shown on the share page as for the first time, but only when I reload the page. * Although it is not shown on the share page, the image is shown and exist on my share content in my facebook homepage.

Why is that happen , is it caused by some incorrect settings of firewall? thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of where this is running ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, please have a look of updated question

Comment: Ok, I will check it out.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I haven't heard of an issue like that before...can I see an example of the fb share + the player though?

Comment: thanks, I will provide you the link

Comment: fixed , I moved the photos to other server and it work as expected

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`og:url` should be of website to which you want to redirect

Comment: Do you mind cleaning up the English here, just a bit, so we are clear what your meaning is?

Comment: this is due to your configurations problem on your host. you can try crosschecking the permissions on these files.

Answer (score 2):

The `og:url` should be the website that contains metadata - in this case you should make website with redirection and metadata or reference **share.php?url=the_url**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only have been misled by the `og:url` parameter:

> `og:url`- The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph

Sounds totally legit, *but*: When you specify that parameter, Facebook fetches the meta data from that URL instead from the current page. This is why you have no meta data when you put the referred URL there. And also the reason for that nasty `share.php?url=share.php?url=share.php...`.

What you are trying to do is done using the `href` attribute: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

I'm not sure what you are building, but maybe this way you even can integrate the share button into the page that you redirect to. Then you still set up that fake meta data page and just throw it into `og:url` in that (formerly redirected to) page then :)

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the demo,wish you gook luck.

http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-create-your-one-facebook-share-url/

by the way,before you test new way.
you had better clear the fb's session. 
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://yourwebsite.com